# How to set the string "value;othervalue" in php.ini with augeas?

Tags: php, puppet, augeas

i want to change the session.save_path in the php.ini with augeas

default:

```
session.save_path="/var/lib/php5"
```

target value

```
session.save_path="3;/var/lib/php5sessions"
```

augeas returns quite interesting results

not working command (save is failing)

```
set /files/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini/Session/session.save_path '"3;/tmp"'
set /files/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini/Session/session.save_path '"3\;/tmp"'
set /files/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini/Session/session.save_path \"3;/tmp\"
```

partly working commands (save works but not the desired result)

```
set /files/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini/Session/session.save_path '"/tmp/test"'
```

is there a way to force augeas to just set the value to the given string and don't try to spit them up

edit:
bug report link: https://fedorahosted.org/augeas/ticket/243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `php.aug` lens (based on `inifile.aug`) does not allow semi-colons in value fields, because they conflict with end-of-line comments, which can use semi-colons, too:

```
let to_comment_re = /[^;# \t\n][^;#\n]*[^;# \t\n]|[^;# \t\n]/
```

If these values should be accepted, please [open a bug report](https://fedorahosted.org/augeas/report) for it.

Comment: then it is a bug. php needs the semicolon for the session.save_path. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path   session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"

Comment: Have you reported it?

Comment: yes: https://fedorahosted.org/augeas/ticket/243

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The bug was fixed.